# Sinon.JS error Invalid URL, How to fix that

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I have attempted try many time but it always not work.
I  using Mocha unit test.
This is my codes unit test:

```
var expect = require("expect");
var jQuery = require("jquery");
var sinon = require("sinon");

describe("SinonFakeServerWithJasmine", function() {
     var server;

     beforeEach(function() {
          server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        server.restore();
    });

    it("should fake a jQuery ajax request", function() {
        server.respondWith("GET", "/something", [200, {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            '{ "stuff": "is", "awesome": "in here" }'
        ]);

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/something",
            success: function() {
                console.log("success");
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });

        server.respond(); // Process all requests so far
    });
```

});

==> And this is log error Jquery.ajax

```
{ readyState: 0,
  getResponseHeader: [Function],
  getAllResponseHeaders: [Function],
  setRequestHeader: [Function],
  overrideMimeType: [Function],
  statusCode: [Function],
  abort: [Function],
  state: [Function],
  always: [Function],
  then: [Function],
  promise: [Function],
  pipe: [Function],
  done: [Function],
  fail: [Function],
  progress: [Function],
  complete: [Function],
  success: [Function],
  error: [Function],
  status: 0,
  statusText: 'TypeError: Invalid URL' }
```

I don't know why it error like that.  I not use expect due to it unnecessary in my case, I want to test sinon with mocha
Thank everyone have spent time read.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same **Invalid URL** issue using Jasmine.

I had to use [xmlhttprequest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest).

```
XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = function() {
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
};
```